# GCS_WGS_1984 Map in Esri Javascript

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system

I created a dynamic map service in Arcmap and published to my server. The spatial reference used: GCS_WGS_1984. I used the javascript without basemap to display in a html. I cannot do a centerandzoom(). I suspect it's the spatial reference because if I add a basemap from esri the centerandzoom() works. How Can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

The [`centerAndZoom`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map.html#centerandzoom) function works different depending on the type of map you're using.

For tiled map services, like ESRI's default base maps, the second parameter is a positive integer that indicates a zoom level.  The values might range from `0` to `15` to select one of the zoom levels that have been pre-rendered into the tiles.

But for dynamic map services like yours, the second parameter to [`centerAndZoom`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map.html#centerandzoom) specifies a zoom factor relative to the current zoom level.  Specifying a value of `1` would mean "no change in zoom level".

What you probably want is the [`setExtent`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map.html#setextent) function instead.  For example, if you wanted to zoom in on California, you could do something like this:

```
var newExtent = new esri.Extent(-125, 32.5, -114, 42, map.spatialReference);
map.setExtent(newExtent);
```